# Python Cassandra will not create a keyspace

Tags: python, cassandra

How can I create a keyspace in Cassandra using Python?

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['cassandra.sucks.com'])
session = cluster.connect()

session.execute('CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS kong')



File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1998, in cassandra.cluster.Session.execute (cassandra/cluster.c:34869)
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3781, in cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result (cassandra/cluster.c:73073)
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting K_WITH">
```

Comment: I would recommend try things in `cqlsh` and use autocomplete first to figure out syntax if you are not going to attempt to read any documentation.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Single Data Center You should create keyspace with the below Query :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS kong WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
```

> 'replication_factor'  Required if class is SimpleStrategy; otherwise, not used. The number of replicas of data on multiple nodes.

or If you have multiple Data Center then use :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS kong  WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3, 'dc2' : 2}
```

> dc1 and dc2 are Data Center name. Required if class is NetworkTopologyStrategy and you provide the name of the data center. This value is the number of replicas of data on each node in that data center.

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html